# MySQL join shows multiple records

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I am using CodeIgniter and in my sql join query it gets duplicate values. For an example if `tbl_employee_contact` has two contact numbers it shows same record twice with different contact number for each. How can I display only one record?

[image: Database image]

[image: Image example]

this is my model

```
function get_records(){
    $this->db->select(array(
         'tbl_employee_registration.emp_id',
         'tbl_employee_registration.emp_fname',
         'tbl_employee_registration.emp_email',
         'tbl_employee_registration.emp_status',
         'tbl_employee_contact.emp_contact',    
    ));
    $this->db->from('tbl_employee_registration');
    $this->db->join('tbl_employee_contact','tbl_employee_contact.emp_id=tbl_employee_registration.emp_id');

    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

this is my controller

```
function manage_operators(){
    $data = array();
    if($query = $this->mod_employee->get_records())
    {
        $data['records'] = $query;
    }
    $this->load->view('admin/admin_manage_operators',$data);
}
```

Comment: This isn't a code igniter problem, and it technically isn't a problem at all. That is how SQL joins work. If you are performing a join on a one to many relationship, then you are going to get "duplicates" of your one table, and all of the different possibilities from the joined table.

Comment: Can you include an example of the tbl_employee_registration and tbl_employee_contact that is causing a problem?

Comment: Yes looks like its one-to-many relation so its showing multiple rows. So how you want to display the data, which row will you keep and which row will get eliminated from the selection ?

Comment: @Abhik Chakraborty it doesn't matter. any row

Comment: @Scott I added Database image in the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `group_by`

```
 $this->db->group_by("your table");
```

finally your model will look like this

```
 function get_records(){
        $this->db->select(array(
            'tbl_employee_registration.emp_id',
            'tbl_employee_registration.emp_fname',
            'tbl_employee_registration.emp_email',
            'tbl_employee_registration.emp_status',
            'tbl_employee_contact.emp_contact',    
        ));
        $this->db->from('tbl_employee_registration');
        $this->db->join('tbl_employee_contact','tbl_employee_contact.emp_id=tbl_employee_registration.emp_id');
        $this->db->group_by("tbl_employee_registration.emp_id");

        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need what's called `GROUP BY` or add `DISTINCT` to your select query.

```
$this->db->select(array(
    'DISTINCT  tbl_employee_registration.emp_id',
    'DISTINCT  tbl_employee_registration.emp_fname',
    'DISTINCT  tbl_employee_registration.emp_email',
    'DISTINCT  tbl_employee_registration.emp_status',
    'DISTINCT  tbl_employee_contact.emp_contact',    
));
```

Or you can select all data but in your loop just add to array with unique IDs like

`$arr[$ID][] = $record`